# Does DOCSIS performance degrade if you have locked channels that are "bad"? Is there some way to disable "bad" channels?

Tags: networking, cable-modem

I have been having bandwidth problems on a home cable internet line.  The ISP seems unable/unwilling to assist in a timely fashion, so I have been reading specs on DOCSIS and such to see if I can at least figure out the problem.

[image: DOCSIS Status Page]

The attached screenshot is from my modem's status page, a few minutes after a reboot.  It seems to me that I have a good number of Downstream channels, locked in and fully functional.  However, it seems that there's a cluster of bad channels, 22-24 in this case.  Multiple reboots seem to suggest that the bad channels are usually the same or similar ones each time.

Could a few bad channels cause a dramatic decrease in performance?  Would I be better off with fewer channels, if it meant not having all these Uncorrectables?  Is there a way to force my modem to do that?  I'm using a [NETGEAR Gateway C7000v2](https://www.netgear.com/support/product/C7000V2.aspx), if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Before overthinking it, I would look into the coax wire and the F-connectors.

- Inspect coax cable, and if you have tight kinks or sharp bends, straighten it or replace the cable if damaged.
- Inspect F-Connectors for proper termination. Make sure the conductor is not too short, and there are no cuts on the conductor. The high freq signal travels on the outer side of the copper, and cuts will cause signal degradation.
- Look for couplers or connectors exposed to elements. If found one, just re-terminate them with new ones and weatherproof them.
- If possible try to reduce number of couplers and splitters.

Comment: This is excellent advise, and I'm doing that as well, but it doesn't seem to completely resolve the issue.